# C# linq XML DeepCompare and tag removal

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I am trying to remove a particular element named `<source file="..." />` from my XML so I can compare them.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML document generated using OCR technology from Nuance Communications, Inc.-->
<document xmlns="http://www.nuance.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <page ocr-vers="OmniPageCSDK16" app-vers="PaperVision Capture">
    <description backColor="d5d3d4">
      <source file="D:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\OCR\\PVCPROCESSING_8\a9cfb6f2-b170-46f6-a00a-2f1557baee26.tmp" dpix="150" dpiy="150" sizex="1279" sizey="1652" />
      <theoreticalPage size="Letter" marginLeft="1700" marginTop="154" marginRight="739" marginBottom="3805" offsetX="-500" offsetY="-20" width="12240" height="15840" />
    </description>
```

I have tried these methods to no avail. It compiles fine but isnt working

```
doc1.Root.Element("document").Descendants().Where(e=>e.Name == "source").Remove();

doc1.Root.Element("document").Elements().Where(e=>e.Name == "source").Remove();

doc2.Root.Elements().Where(e=>e.Name == "source").Remove(); 

doc1.Descendants("document").Where(e=>e.Name == "source").Remove();
```

Anyone have any clues to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You don't use the xnamespace `http://www.nuance.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd`

Comment: Yes I am saving it, I just didnt post that code here. Thats how I know the file still has yet to remove the element.

Comment: What do you mean by not using the xnamespace? I cannot change whats in the xml at this point, because there are many.

Comment: @Krom I posted an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't take *xmlnamespace* into consideration.

See this simple example

```
string xml1 = "<document> </document>";
var elem1 = XDocument.Parse(xml1).Element("document"); //elem1 contains document
```

Now insert a namespace `http://aaa` (as in your case)

```
string xml2 = "<document xmlns=\"http://aaa\"> </document>";
var elem2 = XDocument.Parse(xml2).Element("document"); //elem2 is null
```

*elem2* is null now.

How to solve? use *XNamespace*

```
XNamespace ns = "http://aaa";
var elem3 = XDocument.Parse(xml2).Element(ns + "document"); //elem3 contains document
```

And finally, a more complex example(*see the usage of XmlNamespace*):

```
string xml4 = "<document xmlns=\"http://aaa\"> <subitem> <subsubitem> </subsubitem> </subitem> </document>";
XNamespace ns = "http://aaa";
var elems4 = XDocument.Parse(xml4).Element(ns + "document").Descendants(ns + "subsubitem")
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I believe I am to replace the namespace with http://aaa\ with 
"http://www.nuance.com/omnipage/xml/ssdoc-schema3.xsd" is this correct? I am not sure otherwise where the first came from.

Comment: This is also returning object is not an instance of an object `code`doc1.Element("document").Element("page").Element("description").Element("source").Remove();`code`

Comment: other than the namespace issue is the xdocument.parse going to ignore the xml version and comment that precedes the namespace definition? @L.B